# Can't play Audio

Tags: javascript, html, css, audio

I'm working on a game in html5. I've been trying to figure out how to add audio, I've tried js, and I've tried html, but either one gives me the message:

NotSupportedError: The media resource indicated by the src attribute or assigned media provider object was not suitable.

```
var audio = new Audio('Smile.mp3');
audio.play();
```

```
<audio src="Smile.mp3" id = "sound"></audio>
<script>
var sound = document.getElementById('sound');
sound.play();
</script>
```

I've tried ogg files and mp3 files, which Firefox supports both of. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Where is this code being stored? On a web server or locally on your file system?

Comment: Please only post one question at a time. Edit this question to just be about the audio problem and remove the question about fonts and then post a separate question just about the fonts.

Comment: code is being stored locally @ScottMarcus

Comment: That's most likely your problem. You need to set up a web server and access the files via HTTP. Your server will also need to have the .mp3 Mime Type configured.

Comment: How do I do that? I'm really new to all of this, I'm not sure what to do. @ScottMarcus

Comment: You should Google that. Stack Overflow really isn't a tutorial site where you just post those kinds of questions. We answer specific coding questions.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Is there any way to fix this problem without setting up the web server? I really would prefer to keep it local.

Comment: No. Multimedia is processed by servers with Mime Types configured. It's not as hard as you think. Just google "how to set up my own web server for local use".

Comment: @Link5963 Try some other MP3 file.  I'm not able to reproduce your problem.  Works fine here.

Comment: You can checkout musquito library that helps to make sound easy for games [http://musquitojs.com][1]


  [1]: http://musquitojs.com